# Why isn't importing wallet.dat as straightforward as it seems it should be?

Tags: wallet.dat, private-key-import, private-key-format

In most of computerdom, an app's `File` dropdown menu has an `Import` item that permits selection of a file to import into the application.  This would seem to be an obvious feature to include in a Bitcoin GUI, yet when searching for how one imports the `wallet.dat` file, no such straightforward import option appears.

What is the technical reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not so easy to "open" a wallet, because it requires rescanning the blockchain to find the outputs that are relevant. This can take a very lock time, especially if you do not have an SSD. Because the performance is so poor, it would be disappointing for a lot of users to use this hypothetical feature.

Comment: I see.  So is there client software geared toward those running a full node with SSD, many GB RAM and many cores?  I understand this is a different kind of question from the original.

Comment: @user5652 you could run an electrum-server like electrs or electrumX and then use any electrum-protocol wallet, and configure it to use your local server. the server will need a few hundred gigabytes to index everything.